# Docusign Room api

Tags: docusignapi

When I am hitting Create a room api through Postman with my access token, I am getting this error

```
{
    "errorCode": "ACCESS_DENIED",
    "message": "Access Denied."
}
```

I am trying to hit docusign Room api

```
 https://demo.rooms.docusign.com/restapi/v2/accounts/8049f587-d3fc-4799-99aa-74e00d01a9d1/rooms bu
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a set of specific scopes you need to use before you can request an [access token for Rooms API.](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/rooms-api/rooms101/auth/)

The list includes [image]